# Java Spring MVC app on Tomcat gives error 404

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

[see updates at the bottom] I'm trying to launch a Spring web app via Tomcat, but when I enter the url http://localhost:8080/demo-mvc/ in the browser, I get the 404 error and a message "The requested resource [/demo-mvc/] is not available".
At first I was trying to deploy the app via NetBeans and it said that deployment was successful, but at browser launch I got the 404 error. I checked the Tomcat/webapps directory and didn't find the app directory there somewhy, so I decided to manually pick the app directory from NetBeans' projects folder and move it to webapps (and rename it to demo-mvc for brevity), still there's an error.
The content of app's config files is the following:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
</web-app>
```

spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

There's also a source file HomeController.java

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage()
    {
        return "main-menu";
    }
}
```

and a main-menu.JSP file in the WEB-INF\view location.

UPD: I tried moving the war to webapps, the corresponding folder appeared automatically. Now the requested resource message is gone, but the 404 is still there.

UPD: There are actually two controllers in the app and when I add /hello/showForm to the url, the appropriate page shows up, so there's something wrong with the main page only. The second controller code is:
HelloWorldController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm()
    {
        return "helloworld-form";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm()
    {
        return "helloworld";
    }
    ...
}
```

And there is helloworld-form.jsp in the view folder.

Comment: If you're learning Spring, discard whatever tutorial this is; essentially all of this setup is obsolete. Use Spring Boot with Thymeleaf; it's simpler and more reliable, and you can [generate a standalone project](https://start.spring.io) in one minute, no Tomcat required.

Comment: Yes, I'm learning Spring, but I'm not willing to discard this tutorial, because I'm certain it is useful. Also I am curious about why this is happening.

Comment: You are not using Tomcat 10 by any chance?

Comment: Nope. It's 9.0.52.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved. There was a default index.html file in the webapp directory created by NetBeans. When I deleted that file, the request mapping worked and my index page showed up.